# What is the definition of "complementary distribution"?

Tags: terminology, phonology, compl-distribution

Allophones are defined by means of complementary distribution. As I understand it, a complementary distribution is a "mutually exclusive" relationship between two phones, with regard to a certain phonetic environment. That is, one of the phones will *only* be found in that environment (and nowhere else) while the other phone will *never* be found in that environment (but will be found somewhere else).

For example, In English, [pʰ] and [p] are allophones of the phoneme /p/, since [pʰ] can be found at the beginning of syllables ([pʰɪn]) and nowhere else. Likewise, [p] is never found at the beginning of syllables, but can be found in other positions ([spɪn]). Summarizing in a table:

[image: Phoneme /p/ in English]

Now, in Brazilian Portuguese, [w] and [l] are [considered allophones of /l/](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_phonology#Oral_diphthongs). The reasoning is similar: [l] is never found at the end of syllables, but can be found in other places ([a.'kli.vi], "slope"). [w], on the other hand, is found at the end of syllables ([saw], "salt"). The problem is: [w] *can also be found* elsewhere ([a.'kwi;.fe.ru], "aquifer"). The table for this distribution, therefore, would be like this:

[image: Phoneme /l/ in Brazilian Portuguese]

This means that, in some environments both [w] and [l] can be found, as in the [a.'kli.vi] versus [a'.kwi.fe.ru] example. So, evidently, I'm failing to understand what "complementary distribution" really is. Any help to clarify the concept would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's not that simple as it might seem. Just because two phones are in complementary distribution, it does not automatically make them allophones of the same phoneme - compare English [h] and [ŋ]. Usually another criterion is necessary - of phonetic similarity - and even this one is not sufficient in certain cases.

Comment: The thing is that there are some phonemes with limited (defective, restricted) distribution. And some languages resist a traditional account in phonological theory - compare Kabardian vowels.

Comment: What Alex B. says certainly jibes with what I found at this link:  http://www.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsComplementaryDistributio.htm

Comment: I always think about superman and clark kent. Where one is present, the 'other' necessarily cannot be even though they are 'the same person'. Does that help? Or think of two sides of a coin...

Comment: Consider the words "mal" and "mau", the pronunciation is equal. But I could not find any examples of this in the middle of the word.. as there is "balde" but no "baude", "molde" but no "moude", it seems that there are no such words, and that something is different in those cases, when /l/ as [w] occurs in the middle of the word.

Comment: @Tames there is such a pair, actually: "saudar" and "saldar". Both are pronounced [sawdar]. But I can't see how this is relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: @OtavioMacedo I thought there might have something to it, as I could not think about an example. You are right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need to tease apart the concept of allophony from the concept of complementary distribution.  As people have mentioned in the comments, the two don't necessarily go hand in hand--i.e. it is not necessarily the case that two phones that are in complementary distribution can be assumed to be allophones of the same phoneme (as Alex B. mentioned), nor is it the case that the distribution of two phones--each of which is a possible realization of a single phoneme--will never overlap in their distribution.  It's the second assertion that is relevant for your Brazilian Portuguese example.

The "trick" is that sometimes different phonemes can have allophones "in common", i.e. Phoneme A might sometimes be realized as Phone Y, but Phoneme B might also sometimes be realized as Phone Y:

> /A/ --> [X] in some environment, [Y] in some other environment
>
> /B/ --> [Y] in some environment, [Z] in some other environment

This happens a lot in *neutralizations* and *mergers*.  In languages with word-final devoicing, for example, maybe /d/ is realized as [t] word-finally but as [d] elsewhere.  But /t/ would also be realized as [t] word-finally.  If one encounters a [t] at the end of a word, one cannot be sure without additional information whether it is a realization of /t/ or /d/.

In your example, [w] is probably an allophone of some phoneme that can sometimes be realized as [w] and sometimes [l] (in some sense the "naming" of phonemes is arbitrary, but I'd probably call it /l/ since that seems to be the clear "elsewhere" realization) and [w] is probably also an allophone of a different phoneme (one that I would call /w/).

Now, it is true that *allophones* of the same phoneme must be in complementary distribution, but the two [w]s and the [l] in your table are not actually all realizations of the same phoneme.  So, here is a revised assessment of their distribution, taking their underlying forms into account:

> [l] (from /l/) not found at the end of a syllable, but found elsewhere
>
> [w] (from /l/) found at the end of a syllable, but *not* found elsewhere
>
> [w] (from /w/) found elsewhere (and perhaps also at the end of a syllable?)

So, the [l] and the first [w] are in fact in complementary distribution.  I hope that makes sense!

Comment: It may also be the case that /w/ does not exist as a phoneme in BP, and that [a.'kwi;.fe.ru] contains a phoneme /kʷ/. I'm not saying this is the case - I don't know enough about BP to know. But it is a possibility.

Comment: @Colin you may be right. From the Wikipedia article on Portuguese phonology: "Bisol (2005:122) proposes that Portuguese possesses labio-velar stops /kʷ/ and /ɡʷ/ as additional phonemes rather than sequences of a velar stop and /w/"

Answer (score 1):

complementary distribution mean that the allophones of a particular phoneme occur in different phonetic environment , the phonetic environment determines which of the allophones is used in pronouncing a word . For example ,the two allophones of the phoneme  /p/, namely , [pH] and [p-]are in complementary distribution the first occurs at the end of the word,as in Pat and Pot, the second may occur at the end of the ward   , as in help. the fact of their complementary distribution means that these allophones  do not occur in minimal pairs in English.